# Mistakenly downloaded some Ubuntu repository in Debian. How do I remove them?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, package-management

I have mistakenly downloaded some Ubuntu repository in Debian. 
Now, when I try to update the system `sudo apt-get update` this appears to me:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu bionic InRelease: Ondorengo sinadurak ezin dira egiaztatu gako publikoa ez bait dago eskuragarri: NO_PUBKEY 308C15A29AD198E9
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Ezin da lortu http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I remove the repository to fix the problem?

Comment: Find the repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used `apt-add-repository` to add the repository, run the same command again with the `-r` option, e.g.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
```

If you can't or prefer not to use `add-apt-repository`, then you can remove the repository manually. They're recorded either in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in a file in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. To determine which file is the culprit, run

```
grep y-ppa-manager /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.sources
```

If you added something to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, edit it with

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and remove the offending lines. If you want to remove all the entries in a file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, you can remove the file altogether with

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/y-ppa-manager.list
```

There is also an unrelated error about the `gophers/archive` PPA. If you want it, you need to complete the job of setting it up. You need to do three things to make a package archive available:

1. Add it to the source list (`/etc/apt/sources.list*`).
2. If the archive is signed (which is strongly recommended for security), you need to indicate that you trust its key, by running `sudo apt-key add filename.key`.
3. Run `sudo apt-get update`.

When you use the `ppa:` syntax, `apt-add-repository` takes care of both step 1 and step 2. It seems that step 2 was not performed on your machine. I think you can run `add-apt-repository` (as per [the instructions on the PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~gophers/+archive/ubuntu/archive#ppa-install)) to take care of it. Alternatively, you can add [the key](https://launchpad.net/~gophers/+archive/ubuntu/archive#signing-key) manually with

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key C73998DC9DFEA6DCF1241057308C15A29AD198E9
```

`keyserver.ubuntu.com` is the key server for all Ubuntu PPA keys and is the site that the [signing key link on the PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~gophers/+archive/ubuntu/archive#signing-key) goes to. The hexadecimal string at the end is the fingerprint listed on the PPA page (you can also use the shorter form that's in the error message).

Comment: I had eliminated the "webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu cosmic" following your instructions, but I couldn't fix the "gophers/archive/ubuntu bionic" part.

Comment: @AnderAristondo That's an unrelated problem, but I've added it to my answer anyway.